# How to programmatically login to ASP.NET Identity 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

How do you programmatically login to asp.net identity 2? This is straight forward against Web API, but MVC only project requires __RequestVerificationToken. This is a login method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: By programatically do you mean similar to a unit test?

Answer (score -2):

you must create Login View and in that ,submit your data to this method via ajax call. In this case I prefer using jquery.ajax method instead of ajax form .
Also create LoginViewModel that contains your user info like username , password
so you  use strongly typed view .